# Data Scraper using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the table from this website using beautiful soup however keep getting message dataframe empty.

```
 import requests
 import pandas as pd
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 URL = "https://www.kiplinger.com/article/real-estate/t010-c000-s002-home-price- 
 changes-in-the-100-largest-metro-areas.html"
 page = requests.get(URL)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 table = soup.find('table')

 data = []
 for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
 row = {}
 cells = tr.find_all('td')
  if len(cells) == 3:
    row['Metro Area'] = cells[0].text.strip()
    row['Median Home Price'] = cells[1].text.strip()
    row['Affordability Index'] = cells[2].text.strip()
    data.append(row)


 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 print(df)
```

Im aiming for a dataframe that contain 3 columns. 'Metro Area' , 'Median Home Price' and 'Affordability Index'.

Comment: when I tried the URL, it throws a 404 error, pls check if the URL opens okay in the browser.

Comment: In your code snippet, `URL` is split into 2 lines. Is that a pasting error or is you actual code like that too (although your editor should indicate a syntax error in that case...)? I get [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5adx.png) with just directly running *`pd.read_html("https://www.kiplinger.com/article/real-estate/t010-c000-s002-home-price-changes-in-the-100-largest-metro-areas.html")[0][['Metro Area', 'Median Home Price', 'Affordability Index']]`*

Answer (score 0):

Its necessary to remove the conditional *if* on the 16th line, because the table in this site have six columns (observe the table have six *td* tags), and you have conditioned to add values to the *row* variable if cells was equal to three, so this conditional never will be achieved.

If you remove the entire line of the *if* and proper realign the code, you will obtain the requested solution.